# Getting Uncaught OAuthException: An unknown error has occurred on photo post to target album

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

```
$photo_details = array(
        'message'=> $image->description().' '.$site_adr.$image->id().'/'.cleanSEOstring(strtolower(trim($image->title()))).'-cover-photo',
        'redirect_uri'=> 'http://www.exampleurl.com',
        'scope'=>'publish_stream');
$photo_details['image'] = '@' . realpath($photo);
    try
    {
        $upload_photo = $facebook->api('/'.$album_uid.'/photos', 'POST', $photo_details);
        @unlink($file);
        header('location:https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id='.$userMe['id'].'&v=wall');
    }
    catch(FacebookApiException $e)
    {
        header('location:http://www.somethingwentwrong.com');
    }
```

And it still redirects to somethingwentwrong.com, am I doing something wrong?

The exception, as stated in the title is "An unknwon error has occured", here's the object it returnes in the catch statement:

```
object(FacebookApiException)#5 (7) { ["result:protected"]=> array(1) { ["error"]=> array(3) { ["message"]=> string(30) "An unknown error has occurred." ["type"]=> string(14) "OAuthException" ["code"]=> int(1) } } ["message:protected"]=> string(30) "An unknown error has occurred." ["string:private"]=> string(0) "" ["code:protected"]=> int(0) ["file:protected"]=> string(48) "/var/www/mysite/fb-sdk/base_facebook.php" ["line:protected"]=> int(1106) ["trace:private"]=> array(4) { [0]=> array(6) { ["file"]=> string(48) "/var/www/mysite/fb-sdk/base_facebook.php" ["line"]=> int(810) ["function"]=> string(17) "throwAPIException" ["class"]=> string(12) "BaseFacebook" ["type"]=> string(2) "->"
```

Comment: Why are you setting a `scope` parameter in the data your are POSTing to the `/album-id/photos` endpoint?

Comment: And why are you using different variables – `realpath($photo)` vs. `unlink($file)` – shouldn’t those both be the same, if (I suppose) they are both meant to contain the image’s file name?

Comment: Yes, these are very useful comments indeed, but honestly not very productive, ok, so I`ve overused variables doing the same thing, but even with that and without the scope parameter, it does the same thing.

Comment: Sorry, but “remote debugging” is never easy, and I’m just _trying_ here to find _potential_ issues that might be connected to your problem … If you don’t like that, I’ll be more than happy to let you solve your problem on your own.

Comment: The bounty is not for debugging is for answering why I get "unknown error" exception. If my code was buggy, then it should have had parse errors or logical errors, since it works and this is a Facebook exception I expect facebook graph api related answers not that I`ve used separate variables to do the same thing. If you can't be constructive, please step aside, I really need this solved and really put time in this, I'm sure there will be somebody out there who really focuses on the question here, not on irelevant details. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is your fault. I've been seeing a very similar issue lately, photo uploads are failing with "an unknown error has occurred". This is happening randomly across all of our client accounts, but most frequently on two accounts (80-90% of uploads fail). Sometimes retrying the upload will solve the problem but it usually fails as well.

I've opened a ticket on Facebook Developers area on 9/13. Please add your repro so it gains traction.

http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/258628444257212?browse=search_50688f593127e2295697196

Comment: As a follow up, we were able to work around this issue by adding a new user as admin to the fb page and using auth token for that user.

Comment: Secondary followup - adding another admin and getting a new auth ticket for him worked for a few days, then started failing again. Since 10/6 it appears that facebook has fixed this problem, we haven't seen any photo upload errors since then.

Answer (score 3):

Find out what the exception error message is. So do something like this:

```
} catch {
  error_log('caught exception: '. $e);
  header('location:http://www.somethingwentwrong.com');
}
```

If you get `OAuthException: (#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist` then make sure $album_uid is a string and not an int.

Also make sure the user has given your app the `user_photos` permission.  The exception error message will tell you.

If you are trying to post a photo to an FB Page, you need to use a Page Access Token.

Your code looks ok, except I think `'scope'` and `'redirect_uri'` won't do anything to the Graph API call.

Comment: same thing, and I do have the user_photos permission

Comment: What is the actual text of the exception?  Since you said somethingwentwrong.com is loading, you have exception $e, but I do not see it posted anywhere in this question.  The exception message usually provides useful data.

Comment: Lee: The exception message is:  "An unknown error has occurred." ["string:private"]=> string(0) "" ["code:protected"]=> int(0) ["file:protected"]=> string(48) "/var/www/mysite/fb-sdk/base_facebook.php" If I had more than "An unknown error has occured" ...